# input type="hidden" cannot be obtained from getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, hidden, getelementbyid

A call to `getElementById()` to retrieve a 'hidden' field on a form is returning `null`.

I've studied other SO questions and many were using the hidden field's 'name' instead of 'id' in the call to `getElementById()` or were executing `getElementById()` in a script at top-of-file before the actual html containing the hidden field had been processed by the browser.  Both of those errors would explain why `getElementById()` was returning `null` for them.

I could be wrong but I don't think that's my case here.

This is my form:

```
  <form name="theDeleteItemForm" id="deleteItemForm" action="deleteTheSelectedItem" 
             method="post"
    <input type="hidden" id="theHiddenField" name="deleteThisSelectedItem" value="">
 </form>
```

And here is a Javscript handler that is *successfully* executing when a 'delete' button on the page is clicked (I can tell because my `alert()` boxes in the handler function below are popping up):

```
function deleteItem()
{
    alert("Just entered deleteItem()");

    var theFieldToDelete = document.getElementById('theHiddenField');

     // THIS IS THE PLACE WHERE I FOUND THAT 'theFieldToDelete' WAS 'null'
    alert("Just got the hidden field element, which is: " +  theFieldToDelete );

      // THIS DOES NOTHING MORE THAN TO PREVENT THE 'alert' THAT FOLLOWS FROM APPEARING
    theFieldToDelete.value = "upForDeletion";

    alert("deleteItem() was called, about to submit the form");

    document.theDeleteItemForm.submit();    
}
```

I'm not understanding why I get the `null` return from `getElementById()`.   I'm under the impression that
`getElementById()` works FINE for `type="hidden"` fields.

Furthermore, the id I used for my hidden field -- `theHiddenField`  -- is 100% unique in my file.

Why am I getting `null` when I try to get the hidden field via `getElementById()` ?

Comment: Doubt it's the cause, but your `<input>` tag isn't being closed.  The opening `<form>` tag is also missing its `>`.

Comment: Fix your HTML and this should work properly.

Comment: And make sure your IDs are unique

Comment: What happens if you unhide the field? Does the problem still happen?

Comment: Holy guacamole. Burned 15 minutes of life on a missing '>' to close the opening <form> tag.  The <input> doesn't need to be closed as per http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp at least for HTML.  Thanks guys -- I got into a staring contest with my code and lost, closing the <form  by changing the above code to method="post">  solved the problem -- I'm now getting a non-null return element from getElementId -- thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably it's because your `<form>` element isn't formed properly (as in quoted example - the `>` is missing in the opening tag)?

Answer (score -1):

use document.getElementById('theHiddenField').value

Comment: It's correct that this will be needed, but something else is going on. This wouldn't prevent the getElementById portion from returning null. If it's null without the .value, it will be undefined with the .value.